# SSH - Key signing of ED25519 style keys does not work

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, certificates

Trying to set up a SSH Cert Authority so I can centralize new key setup rather than modifying the `authorized keys` on each of my machines.  I found something really odd - the keys that I develop work only if the user keys are RSA style keys and will fail with ED25519 style keys.  I tested and the failure happens depending on the user key type, so RSA user keys can be signed by both RSA and ED25519 style CA keys but then surprisingly a ED25519 key CA can signs RSA keys which work but when the same CA is used to sign ED25519 keys, the resulting key will not work.

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f userkey
ssh-keygen -s my-ssh-ca-private-key -I some-identifier userkey.pub
cat userkey userkey-cert.pub > key_with_cert`

When I take the `key_with_cert` file to the new computer; it works if and only if I remove the "*-t ed25519*".  The output from `ssh -vv -i key_with_cert user@example.com`:

RSA style key that works

https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/backblaze-b2-public/debug_output_rsa

ED255519 style key using "*-t ed25519*" that fails

https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/backblaze-b2-public/debug_output_ed25519

Any ideas on why the key type is causing a problem?  ED25519 has been around for a while so I expect similar handling between RSA and ECC keys.

Comment: Please run ssh with the "-vv" flag to print debugging output. Then [edit] your question to include the ssh command that you ran and the debugging output.

Comment: @Kenster - done, linked as external files since quite verbose (haha).  Do let me know any other info to help clarify